# hit learning curves head-on everywhere

Tags: comprehension

From the book [Thinking in Java](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIJ/):

> OK, I’ve only read about 40 pages of Thinking in Java, but I’ve already found it to be the most clearly written and presented programming book I’ve come across...and I’m a writer, myself, so I am probably a little critical. I have Thinking in C++ on order and can’t wait to crack it—I’m fairly new to programming and **am hitting learning curves head-on everywhere**. So this is just a quick note to say thanks for your excellent work. I had begun to burn a little low on enthusiasm from slogging through the mucky, murky prose of most computer books—even ones that came with glowing recommendations. I feel a whole lot better now. Glenn Becker, Educational Theatre Association

What does he really mean by that? I don't think I understand that part. Does it mean that he's struggling because he's new to programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "hit {something}" is a figurative term; it means "to encounter".

**You might hit heavy traffic on the way to the airport.**

The writer of the passage seems  to want to wrest  "hit" away from its figurative meaning when he adds "head on", which pulls the verb back to its literal meaning of "smash into".

**The driver lost control of the car and hit the tree head on.**

"Head on" means "directly", that is, not at an angle.

Finally, "learning curves" are a commonplace metaphor (a cliche, really) and they are often said to be "steep", a word that describes a *slope*. The metaphor is one of *ascent*. We do not normally *hit hills head on*.

All things considered,  the author has little cause to throw stones at other writers.

> I had begun to burn a little low on enthusiasm from slogging through
>   the mucky, murky prose of most computer books...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When we say becoming proficient in a certain discipline entails a learning curve, we mean to say that there's some degree of difficulty that the learner will experience while doing so, especially at the beginning of the process. The Wikipedia entry for "[Learning curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_curve)" has some graphical representations and a more precise definition of what learning curves actually are.